# Where I can find the GNOME key binding scheme files stored?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, dconf

I want to personalize my system wide key bindings, where I find these files and what package has them?

Comment: Hmm. I think this question has been asked before, though not answered. Keep your eye out ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system wide schemas are in the `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` directory, where there are all the dconf configurations for the entire system. If you want to modify the key bindings you should look to:

```
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.gschema.xml
```

These controls the Media, Terminal shortcut, magnifier, accessibility tools, screenshots, etc. This is the system wide equivalent to:

[image]

and you should write the file using the xml entities for symbols, `<` becomes `&lt;`, etc.